# jquery: selecting the <caption> element

Tags: jquery, drupal

I'm in Drupal. Sigh. Tables are output with a `<caption>`, no classes/id's so I'm trying to append the word "new" to the caption of a table, but only if that table contains products which start with "GW6D"..

Since the tables are dynamically output via Views, I don't have access to the straight caption tag in the html to add a class. (I can't do it in a template because then every caption would have that class so I'd then be trying to figure out how to select captions of tables w/o the right products and removing that class)

I've tried:

```
var target = $("table.views-table td:contains('GW6D')").closest("table");
$(target).each(function(){
    $(this).prepend('<span class="newProdStyling">New</span>');
    });
```

Which applies the word. I can put 'tr', 'td' in that selector but I can't seem to target the actual  tag if I use `.closest("caption");`. Right now, this snippet will append a 'new' for each prod so though it's creating too many 'news' right now, I just want to get it to prepend the `<caption>` tag.

I'm also stuck with jquery 1.3.2 but I haven't found anything that says tageting `<caption>` is version specific.

barebones jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/UbtmJ/4/

Comment: Can you post some sample HTML, and what you're trying to change it to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<caption>` is not a parent of the `td` elements (*that is why `closest` does not find it*). But it is inside the `<table>` so you have to go downwards once you reach that..

```
var target = $("table.views-table td:contains('GW6D')").closest("table").find('caption');
$(target).prepend('<span class="newProdStyling">New</span>');
```

Comment: Great! That was my problem, not knowing that closest is looking for a parent...I'll accept when it lets me. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

`.closest()` doesn't "look around" for a match, it traverses *up* through the current element's ancestors in the DOM tree. (See [the documentation here](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)).

Having found the table with `.closest('table')`, you then need to traverse *downwards* to find the caption. The easiest function for that is [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).

So your target would be:

```
var target = $("table.views-table td:contains('GW6D')").closest("table").find("caption");
```

Incidentally, the result of all this is a jQuery object, so you don't need to wrap it in `$()` afterwards; this would be fine:

```
target.each(function(){
    $(this).prepend('<span class="newProdStyling">New</span>');
});
```

As would this:

```
$("table.views-table td:contains('GW6D')")
    .closest("table")
    .find("caption")
    .each(function(){
        $(this).prepend('<span class="newProdStyling">New</span>');
    });
```